# fastest gate setup to add 7 integer of 32bits

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to add 7 integer of 32 bit each together, using gates. The naive solution is to add two together, than the sum of these two with the third integer. The the sum of the first three added to the fourth integer... etc. However this is probably the slowest solution. I am looking for a fast way to do it. This is for sha256 algorithm. The main speed bottleneck is caused by a 7 input 32 bit adder.

Consider the 32 bit labelled: a, b, c, d, e, f, g. I would like to output a+b+c+d+e+f+g using gates asap.

A faster way would be

```
(((a + b) + (c + d)) + ((e + f) + (g)))   //This is performed in 3 steps.

(((((((a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g)    //This is performed in 6 steps.
```

I would like to know if it can be done faster than the 3 steps process, by using special adders that can take multiple inputs.

Comment: Also, I might add that in your 3-step scheme, you need to feed signal with "slower path" into g, but I guess that's quite obvious. Decent logic syntheses would be able to optimize this further, effectively merging these stages where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your 3-stage adder would likely be the best possible. You need to balance the need for an adder with multiple inputs, and mulitple stages of adding. You could probably end up designing a 7-input adder from scratch, but it would probably be terribly slow due to its complexity.

That said, if your goal is to speed up your SHA implementation, you may sometimes need to take a big-picture view on the system.

Comment: The term for the "3 Stage Adder" is an Adder Tree. They come in just about any number of inputs.  Not to be confused with the Tree Adder, which is a poisonous snake.

Comment: @David - Why does your comment have more upvotes than sybreon's answer?

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer  My ballot-stuffing minions are finally working.  Now it's time to announce by 2012 campaign.  But seriously, I gave Sybreon my +1, so I'm doing my part!  :)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest practical approach is probably to build a circuit which takes three inputs and returns a two-bit count of how many of the inputs are high (look up 'carry-save adder').  If the inputs are A, B, and C, the ouputs are (AB or AC or BC, A xor B xor C).  Using 32 of these, one can easily produce a circuit that takes three 32-bit numbers and after two gate delays returns two numbers whose sum is that of the original three.

To add seven numbers, take the first six numbers as two groups of three and turn them into four numbers (so a total of five numbers will remain to be added).  Repeatedly take three of those numbers and munge them to produce two, until one has only two numbers left.  At that point, one may then add the two remaining numbers using a "conventional" adder.

Another approach would be to use a 7-to-3 carry-save adder; there are various approaches with different numbers of gate delays and levels of fan-in.  Perhaps divide the input into a group of 3 and a group of 4; use two logic stages to develop outputs for at-least-one, at-least-two, at-least-three, or all-four inputs active, and then use another two logic stages to combine these into at-least-one through at-least-seven.  Two more logic stages will suffice to produce the three-bit result from the carry-save adder, and two more will turn that into two bits.  One probably ends up with more circuitry than would be needed using 3:2 carry-save adders, but a somewhat faster logic path (max gate fan-in would be six).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be analogous to the carry-save accumulator often used in multipliers. The basic idea is that when you add two numbers ( X1 + X2 ) What you get is a new pair ( S + C ), where S contains the sum outputs of the 32 half-adders, and C the carry outputs (shifted one position to the left so they are in the appropriate place). Hence C[0] is 0.

In the next step you add S + C + X3 (using full adders), and you again get an S' + C' pair, in which C'[0] = 0. You repeat this for all integers you want to add. The important point is these additions are not slowed down by any form of carry propagation, so they can be fast (and small in gates).

As a last step you will need to add the final S + C, using any means available.

So your total time is 7 three-way additions without carry propagation, plus one full-side two-way addition with carry.

When used for multiplication the situation is even better, because last step is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Carry select adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_select_adder) should be a good choice. It requires a lot of hardware, but is also very efficient.